# IOS: How to allow both triggered segues and sent actions using only a tap gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am creating a simple game that has a specific image,like a menu button, with a tap gesture. The tap gesture calls a method and goes to a View controller(menu of my game). My problem is when I tap this image, it is ignoring the second action. The image below describes better my tap gesture.
PS: getBackToMenu is my method that sets some attributes of my game.

[image]

Comment: Don't trigger the segue directly from the button.  Use `performSegueWithIdentifier:` from your `getBackToMenu` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are doing here is triggering segue directly from button. Because  of this segue is being performed first.

Do One thing remove segue from button to view controller and create segue between controllers with some identifier.

then implement this method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER"])
    {
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
 }
```

Then on button press event perform segue using this method

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
//Do your primary task here Then Call performseguewithidentifier method
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" sender:sender];}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are about to perform the segue action, you can add some codes in

```
－(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

You can get the destination controller using **segue.destinationController**, and then set some attribute there as just passing some data.

By the way, you can identify which segue works, add

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueName"])
```